# Guys can you please help me install ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, windows, uefi, windows-10

I have an Acer Laptop with the following specification: 
CPU: Intel Core i7-6500 2.5GHz with Turbo Boost up to 3.1GHz
Graphics Card: NVIDIA GeForce 940M with 2GB Dedicated VRAM
RAM: 8GB DDR3 L Memory
HDD: 100GB (1 TB)

---

I need to install Ubuntu on my laptop but at the same time keeping Windows 10. I have a UEFI bios. I tried many YouTube videos but none of them worked. What happens is that when I installed Ubuntu, the dual boot menu doesn't show. Windows 10 would just load automatically. Can you please help me in regards to how to solve this problem? And what things I should have my laptop at to be able to dual boot. 
Ubuntu is very important for my studies. 
Thank you!

Comment: Please run the [Boot Info Script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/). This will generate a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Post that file to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and post the URL to your document here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which is required to base an answer on more than guesswork.

Answer (score 0):

Under Windows, you can download and install [Grub2win](https://sourceforge.net/projects/grub2win/) and you'll be good to go. Please follow all of the instructions given by it. The first time you start up Grub2win control panel you'll have to install it by clicking on the yellow button (can be green too, just the upper one).

I hope this will help you.

-Thijs365

Comment: Do I have to have Ubuntu installed before I install Grub2win, thank you for answering

Comment: @JamesKyorn it would be best to do that

Comment: Thank you very much just one more questions. I have a laptop so is there anything that I need change in the bios or power options to make this work?

Comment: Any that you recommend

Comment: In the UEFI, set the first boot device to GRUB, GRUB2, GRUB2Win or anything which looks like that. But I assume your automatically booting into Grub2win,